# Airflow: schedule_interval = '@once'

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

What is the semantic difference between setting airflow's `schedule_interval` to `"@once"` vs. `None`?

If I understand correctly, they both will require manual triggering of the dag in order to run. Is this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Only if set to `None` you have to trigger it manually - it won't be scheduled at all.
If you set it to `@Once` it will run exactly one time (and only one time) - [see the airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/scheduler.html).

Comment: Can you still manually trigger a dag multiple times, if it has schedule `@once`?

Comment: Yes, you can trigger it manually multiple Times - the schedule_interval affects only the (Automatic) scheduler